# MongoDB - Get all elements inside a BsonArray and convert into List<string>

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with a document containing a `BsonArray`. Like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": ""
  },
  "Types": [
    "Type 1",
    "Type 2",
    "Type 3"
  ]
}
```

I want to get all the "Type" values inside "Types" so I can create a List of strings in C#, I can get the document containing the `Types` array but I can't create the List because the result I get is of type `BsonElement`.

This is my code so far:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("Types", true);
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Types").Exclude("_id");
var result = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).First();
```

The projection seems to be working because the result I get is this but I can't get the elements in a list.

```
Types=["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand your question, you are trying to convert from `BsonArray` to `List<string>`.

Working with *System.Linq* to convert each `BsonValue` to `string` type and output the result with `List<string>` type.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<string> types = ((BsonArray)result["Types"]).Values
    .Select(x => x.AsString)
    .ToList();
```

[image]